# Can I let the color of the GPX track be determined by values associated with each track point, e.g. elevation or speed?

Tags: colors, openlayers, gpx

My gpx file already contains elevation information for each trkpt and I can augment this with a speed for each trkpt. I would like to represent the elevation or the speed at each trkpt by varying the color of the track. For instance: slow is blue, fast is red.

How can I do this?

And this probably means: Which files and functions in Openlayers do I have to change to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `ol/style/FlowLine` of [ol-ext](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext) to achieve this.

Using this style, you can change the with/color of the feature along the line using a function. This example show how to: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.flowline2.html.
You just have to calculate the width (or color) along the feature geometry varying according the speed or altitude:

```
const flowStyle = new ol.style.FlowLine({
  width: function(f, step) { 
    // calculate the with of the feature f at the given step
    // step is the curvilinear abscissa between 0,1 
    // (0: first coordinate, 1: last one)
    const width = ...
    return width;
  }
});
```

@+

Answer (score 0):

You should go with a stylefunction for the vector layer:

https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.html#.StyleFunction

This function is checked for each feature to be displayed on the vector layer and the related style can be set/returned programmatically. For example:

```
function gpxStyle(feature) {
    var style = null;
    if (feature.get("speed")>="100") {
        style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 6,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: 2
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'red'
          })
        })
        });
    }
    else {
        style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 6,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'blue'
          })
        })
        });
    }
    return [style];
}

var gpxLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: gpxStyle
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. I want to change the color at each trackpoint (and read the extension of each trackpoint to determine that color). This answer sets one color for all trackpoints in the track. It may be that this is not supported by the current version of openlayers.